# AEM 6: How to customize Reviews Essentials Component

Tags: aem, sling

I would like to customize the standard component [Reviews Essentials](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/de/aem/6-0/develop/social-communities/essentials/reviews.html). For this Purpose I have copied `libs\social\reviews\components\hbs\reviews\review.review.hbs` to `apps/myProject/components/social/reviews/hbs/reviews/review.hbs` in my Project. In this file I have added some `<dev>test</dev>` just to test, if the copied file `review.hbs` override the original file. I have deployed and tested but nothing changes :(. Do I have to do something else to tell the framework to use my `review.hbs` instead of the original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting your changes in a directory starting with */apps/**myProject/components...*** means that you started to create your own component identified with the sling:resourceType:

***myProject/components***/social/reviews/hbs/reviews

instead of just creating an overlay that extends or modifies the default component with the sling:resourceType ***social/reviews/components/hbs/reviews***

To extend the default social review component with your adaptions requires to create an overlay in /apps but without your project specific prefixes:

***/apps/social/reviews/components/hbs/reviews/reviews.hbs***